# Font gets replaced

Tags: font

I'm having the following problem! My fonts get replaced in multiple programs (E.g. twitter, itunes, tweetdeck) It all looks like the screenshot I added below. I don't know how this came all of a sudden and it's really anoying, does anyone know what I can do to solve this problem?

I tried: rebooting and resolve standard fonts in font-book.

Thanks a lot!

[image: font get replaced]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get [Onyx](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/11582/onyx), go into Cleaning -> Fonts, check all, Execute.

If that doesn't work, check your disk for errors.  If it still doesn't work, your fonts are are missing or corrupt - reinstall OS X.

Comment: You could also use the Apple Type Services utility: `sudo atsutil databases -remove; sudo atsutil server -shutdown; sudo atsutil server -ping`